# 555 timer producing 3x expected frequency in astable mode

Tags: oscillator, 555

I’ve just started experimenting with electronics, and for my first project I made an oscillator with a 555 in astable mode. I used two 56k resistors and a 0.1 uF capacitor for the C1. I also included another 0.1 uF from pin 5 to ground. A calculator shows this should produce around 128 Hz, but my oscilloscope measures  around 361 Hz which is ≈ 3x what was expected.

Is there something wrong with my oscilloscope or is the problem with my circuit?

[image: this is my 555 breadboard circuit pictured below]

Comment: Could you reference where you got the schematic? I'm curious about the diode there.

Comment: There are several possible oscillator circuits. Please draw a schematic.

Comment: Are those actually 56k resistors? That would be green blue black red, I don't see a red band.

Comment: I didn’t use a schematic I used this tutorial on YouTube: https://youtu.be/q0aVOIehsQ4?si=qtztuN3adlzs5XLp

Comment: The diode allows for a 50% duty cycle

Comment: @periblepsis The diode goes from discharge to threshold to get less than 50% duty cycle

Comment: They are 5 band color coded resistors: green blue black red brown is the order edit from orange to red

Comment: Yes they are 56k resistors I tested that too. Also for the video I forgot to mention the values are different

Comment: @Chickenguy5 Doesn't look like red at all in the photo.

Comment: @GodJihyo might have been because I had to compress the photo to get it under 3Mib. In real life it looks like it is red

Comment: Well, I don't see anything obvious wrong with the circuit, some possibilities are an off value capacitor or something with your scope. Are you reading the freq right from the trace or relying on a built in freq counter? If the latter maybe it's measuring a harmonic.

Comment: That’s possible. I tested the signal with a passive buzzer and it seemed to be producing lots of harmonics . All of my components and equipment are very cheap off of Amazon so that might be the problem. I think it would be a good idea to close this question. I don’t know how.

Comment: Your capacitor has a 20% tolerance.  And the diode (without a circuit) to get 50% duty cycle will throw off the actual numbers.  Post a legitimate schematic and someone will analyze it.

Comment: No schematic. Everyone else puts pin one in the lower left. I just wasted a lot of time since I misinterpreted the circuit. I will never learn.

Comment: @mattman944 mistakes happen. I fried my first 555 because  I thought pin 5 was on the top right and not the bottom right so basically I had the whole right side of pins flipped

Answer (score 2):

This is your current schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr3LXD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the timing capacitor charges through R1 and discharges through R2 (ignoring diode drop). Without the diode it would charge through R1+R2 and discharge through R2 so you would not get close to 50% duty cycle (and you'd get a lower frequency).

I would expect a frequency of roughly

\$ F_O = \frac{1.44}{(56\text{k}Ω + 56\text{k}Ω)0.1\mu F} \$

For which I get 128Hz, which agrees you with your calculator.

As to what might be wrong with your circuit:

1. (especially) for the bipolar 555 you **must** have a bypass capacitor
   near the power pins. Something like 100uF or 470uF electrolytic. Otherwise the changes in the transition voltage can cause the oscillator to run faster than expected.
2. The 100nF small disc ceramic capacitor is suspect for a timing capacitor. It's fine for the control voltage bypass. A film capacitor (eg. polyester) would be better. Many ceramic capacitors have egregiously large voltage coefficients and so would tend to cause the oscillator to run faster than expected.

The circuit will be somewhat sensitive to supply voltage. You'll get closer results to theoretical with a higher supply voltage such as 9V than  you would with 5V or less. The diode is not ideal (a 1N4148 or similar would be better) but at 100Hz it is not likely your problem unless it's a Schottky type (eg. 1N5819) - in which case leakage could be increasing the frequency. A 1N400x type should be okay at low frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the answer: the 0.1uf capacitor was either mislabeled or faulty. I replaced it with a 2.2nf film capacitor and it tested at the exact right frequency 5.86khz. It could also be that my scope is less accurate in the lower frequency range.

Comment: Please correct the “0.1pf”.